# Print all possible strings of a given length

Tags: java

> Given a string of alphabets and a number k, write a function to print all of the combinations of length k of these alphabets.
>
> The string does not contain duplicate alphabets.
>
> **Input**: `{ 'a', 'b', 'd', 's', 'e' }`
>
> **Expected output**: `abd, abs, abe, ads, ade, bds, bde, bse, dse`

I'm using recursion.

The base case would be when the int `k` is 0, return the prefix.

If the base case is not met, step-by-step, add all the characters from the character array and recursively call for `k = k - 1`.

```
// Recursive method used to print all possible strings of length k, given a set of characters.
private static void printAllCombinations(char[] alphabet, String prefix, int n, int k) {
    // Base case: k is 0,
    // print prefix.
    if (k == 0) {
        System.out.print(prefix + " ");
        return;
    }

    // One by one add all characters
    // from set and recursively
    // call for k equals to k - 1.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // Next character of input added.
        String newPrefix = prefix + alphabet[i];

        // k is decreased, because
        // we have added a new character.
        printAllCombinations(alphabet, newPrefix, n, k - 1);
    }
}
```

**Actual output**: `aaa aab aad aas aae aba abb abd abs abe ada adb add ads ade asa asb asd ass ase aea aeb aed aes aee baa bab bad bas bae bba bbb bbd bbs bbe bda bdb bdd bds bde bsa bsb bsd bss bse bea beb bed bes bee daa dab dad das dae dba dbb dbd dbs dbe dda ddb ddd dds dde dsa dsb dsd dss dse dea deb ded des dee saa sab sad sas sae sba sbb sbd sbs sbe sda sdb sdd sds sde ssa ssb ssd sss sse sea seb sed ses see eaa eab ead eas eae eba ebb ebd ebs ebe eda edb edd eds ede esa esb esd ess ese eea eeb eed ees eee`

What can I do differently to achieve the desired output?

I understand that my function, `printAllCombinations` is actually working as it should. I just don't understand how I can achieve the desired output.

Comment: How do you interpret and implement the rule that "The string does not contain duplicate alphabets.". Many of your strings contain duplicate letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `n` to keep track of your current location in the array `alphabets`.

```
public static void printAllCombinations(char[] alphabet, int k) {
    printAllCombinations(alphabet, "", 0, k);
}
private static void printAllCombinations(char[] alphabet, String prefix, int n, int k) {
    if (k == 0) { //base case unchanged
        System.out.print(prefix + " ");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = n; i < alphabet.length; i++) { //loop only from n to end of array
        String newPrefix = prefix + alphabet[i];

        printAllCombinations(alphabet, newPrefix, i + 1, k - 1);
    }
}
```

Output: `abd abs abe ads ade ase bds bde bse dse`

If you want the commas before every element except for the first one then you can change your base case to this:

```
if (k == 0) {
    if (n > prefix.length()) {
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.print(prefix);
    return;
}
```

Which will output: `abd, abs, abe, ads, ade, ase, bds, bde, bse, dse`